# Whats is the best Windows VPS hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, vps, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm currently using shared hosting.
I want more control over my IIS and also I need to run in full trust.
There are a lot of options out there for Windows VPS hosting.

Which ones do you recommend is the best?

Some must haves

- Has to have great support
- Automatic hardware fail overs
- Access through Remote Desktop (you would be amazed some don't offer this)
- No limit on what I can install on it

Comment: I've asked similar [question with more limited scope](http://serverfault.com/questions/133100/what-is-the-solid-windows-server-2008-vps-hosting-preferably-in-europe) some time ago at serverfault but I didn't receive feedback I hoped for.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Is this out of scope?  Can someone elaborate??

Comment: Please don't downvote without stating your reason. Should this perhaps be turned into a wiki question?

Comment: It's subjective, but IMO this question is way too broad to be in scope for this site. References: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104/is-a-question-about-web-hosts-appropriate (and other similar questions on Meta)

Comment: You'll probably want to be more specific on which web hosts you have in mind. Maybe a more targeted question asking for input on how hosts compare on a certain subject. There are 1 billion hosting companies out there and everyone has Their Opinion™

Comment: There's a pattern you'll notice with "Recommend me (X)" questions. Also, as @Jakub pointed out: http://serverfault.com/questions/12655/cheap-vps or http://serverfault.com/questions/101341/cheap-vps-hosting http://serverfault.com/questions/808/who-is-your-favorite-vps-provider - obviously they're on a different site so nobody expects you to have found them, but it sets a precendence.

Comment: I was hoping people would recommend a number of hosts and then the crowd would help sort out which one is the best.

Answer (score 2):

[Maximum ASP](http://www.maximumasp.com/) is highly regarded.

Comment: These guys seem expensive

Answer (score 1):

I have had good experience with SoftSys Hosting.  They have great pricing ($50/month for 2GB RAM and 2 CPU) and I have found the support and communications to be excellent.  The only one of your requirements I am unsure whether or how they support is automatic hardware failover.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've not personally used them, I hear that [PowerVPS](http://www.powervps.com/) is quite good.

Comment: Looks like these guys only offer linux.

Answer (score 0):

The new Amazon **EC2 micro instances** are the best Windows/Linux "VPS" servers in my opinion: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/09/09/announcing-micro-instances-for-amazon-ec2/

Their price is around the same as a normal VPS but you get the complete Amazon backend structure. The downside is that the EC2 system has a learning curve and AWS support is *not* free (except the forums).

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, for anyone looking at the answers, check out **Burst.net**. I have no affiliation with them but they offer **GREAT** prices on VPS and dedicated servers for Linux and Windows.

I have one of each and I can't complain, only give praise.